# splitting semidirect product

Tags: semidirect-product, group-extensions

Let $1\rightarrow G{\rightarrow}^\varphi E\rightarrow^\psi H\rightarrow 1$ be short exact sequence of groups and homomorphisms where $E$ is a semidirect product $E=G \rtimes H$.

I am struggling to see why does this short exact sequence split? That is, why is there a homomorphism $\gamma : H\rightarrow E$, such that $\psi \gamma = 1_H$?

edit: fixed $1_H$.

Comment: If there is no further information on the maps, the statement is false. (It is even false for direct products of abelian groups)

Comment: Can you provide counterexample?

Comment: There is no further information on the maps.

Comment: Consider the the exact sequence $$0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \times \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to 0$$
where the first map is multiplication by $p$ on the first factor and the second map is $(n,x) \mapsto (n \mod p, x)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example!